# Booking Syntax error SQL

Tags: mysql

I did a trigger but it's giving me an error message, it must be a syntax issue. Does anyone see any problem with this.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER Carperperson
BEFORE INSERT ON bookings
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF NEW.customer_id = bookings.customer_id
                and ((new.start_date >= bookings.start_date and new.start_date < bookings.end_date)
                        or (new.end_date > bookings.start_date and new.end_date < bookings.end_date))
THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' set message_text='You can only book one car per single customer a day!';


DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Can you explain in human language what is the intent of your trigger?

Comment: yeah sure! so it's supposed to not allow a single customer rent more than one car. e.g. John cannot book a Ford and a Skoda. Firstly he has to return the Ford.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a table like:

```
create table bookings 
( customer_id int not null
, start_date date not null
, end_date date not null
, car_id int not null );
```

I suspect the problem with your trigger is that `bookings.customer_id` does not refer to something in this context. You can try something like:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER Carperperson
BEFORE INSERT ON bookings
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM bookings 
    WHERE NEW.customer_id = bookings.customer_id
      AND ((new.start_date >= bookings.start_date 
            and new.start_date < bookings.end_date)
        or (new.end_date > bookings.start_date 
            and new.end_date < bookings.end_date))
) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
        set message_text='You can only book one car per single customer a day!' ;
END IF;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

An alternative approach is to store one row per date:

```
create table bookings 
( customer_id int not null
, booking_date date not null
, car_id int not null );
```

A constraint like:

```
ALTER TABLE bookings ADD CONSTRAINT pk_bookings
    PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, booking_date);
```

Achieves the same thing. To prevent the same car to be rented by several customers you can add a constraint like:

```
ALTER TABLE bookings ADD CONSTRAINT ak_bookings
    UNIQUE (car_id, booking_date);
```

Comment: Sir you are amazing, this is one of the best answers I had so far. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Still allows me to book another car for someone else who already rented :/!

Comment: Sure, but so does your trigger and in the comment, you say " it's supposed to not allow a single customer rent more than one car". You can add another UNIQUE constraint on  (car_id, booking_date).